# Western blotting of lung samples

Tags: lab-techniques, western-blot

I have been working on lung samples to perform western blotting. I have two related questions about this:

1. I get very nonspecific results: at times nothing at all, at times it glows on membrane but doesn't take up on x-ray film. What are the common causes of these errors and how might I avoid them?
2. I am interested in assaying GPCR expression. When I am assaying for GPCRs, do I need to prepare the lung samples in a specific way (that is different from sample preparation for Western blots of other proteins)?

Comment: You may be interested in this: http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/7205/how-to-do-western-analysis-to-lung-tissue

Comment: I wrote the answer to the above question, please let me know if you're still having issues. Just leave a comment with @MattDMo in it.